# How to determine response status for exception handler?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, exception, http-response-codes

I use exception handler in my controllers like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
@ResponseBody
public ApiError handleException(Exception e) {
    logger.error("Exception occurred {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    return new ApiError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, e.getMessage());
}
```

Now I thought about choosing the right response status depends on exception type. Is there any relation in best practices?

The modern way is using Runtime exception everywhere so am not sure that it is always correct to use `4XX` response codes for all Runtime exceptions.

Could you clarify?

### P.S.

I understans that 4XX is client error, but 5XX is server error.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it just does not depend on a runtime vs checked exception pattern, but on a semantically right differentiation.

- The type of exceptions does not reflect this semantic by default.
- 5xx is telling the client that something went wrong at you side.
- 4xx is telling the client that the API is used "wrong" or not in an expected way.
- You can implement a 4xx or 5xx status code with runtime or checked exceptions. It just depends on your own software architecture.
- I would not determine 4xx/5xx from the differentiation of checked or runtime exceptions (seems to harm the [principle of least astonishment - POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment))

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I just throw a custom Exception back to the controller when something goes wrong at runtime, and a ResponseEntity is automatically created, returning my Exception with a HttpStatus code. I try to keep as often as possible a logic, and to return the clearer code along with the message and the exception string name.

Like : 
HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED when a pre-treatment fail (not because of the client payload tho)
HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST when something is wrong in the payload received from client
HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT when something is OK but we return empty response cause no result is found
 etc ...

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. In my opinion, it is not always correct to return `4xx` response codes for all unchecked exceptions. I would rather map a defined subset of those exceptions to `4xx` response codes and anything else should be an internal server error, thus `500` response code.

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class EntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
  // ...
}
```

This exception can be thrown from `@Service` annotated classes if the entity is not found. For the other cases, you could define custom exceptions as well. You can also stick to you `@ExceptionHandler`, but then you would have to do the mapping yourself.

I should be good practise to map exceptions to related HTTP response codes:

- Bad Request: `400`
- Not Found: `404`
- Forbidden: `403`
- Internal Server Error: `500`

Also, do not forget to return one of the following (or any other) response code, if your request was successful.

- OK: `200`
- Created: `201`

Above response codes are commonly used. Of course, there are a lot more, but most APIs only take a small subset. With correct mapping, it is easier for clients to know what possibly went wrong (or right) and then can carry out further actions or display the client neccessary information. For example:

- `200`: show a success message
- `403`: redirect to the login page
- `400`: show errors if a form was submitted

It is also good practise to include meaningful information in the body if anything went wrong. This answers also the question: "What should i do if i cannot map an exception to an existing response code?". I have asked myself the same question and the answer is simple. Try to map it to the closest response code and include anything else in the body.

If the client is missing a parameter you could use the following:

```
{ "error" : "Bad Request - Your request is missing parameter 'id'. Please verify and resubmit." }
```

Or for above mentioned forms errors (response code `400`):

```
{ 
    "errors": [
        "username": "AlreadyInUse",
    ]
}
```

Just make sure you stick to **one** format when returning information in the body. Otherwise, it is a pain to work with.